# Implementing Click on anywhere on Layout

Tags: android

I want to implement Click on anywhere on Layout but for some reason app get stopped and I don't understand why. here is relevant part of my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
....
    private TextView Issue;
 ....
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


 ////here is where I code to touch screen  
 RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        rlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

               mp.stop();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I also tried `OnClickListener` instead of `setOnTouchListener` and it didn't solve. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your relativelayout clickable

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then use onclicklistener

```
rlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         mp.stop();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.Don't forget to add `setContentView`**

**2.Set `RelativeLayout` as global variable, it will be used in other method**

**3.Use `setOnClickListener` on `RelativeLayout`**

```
private RelativeLayout rlayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // add setContentView here
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //here is where I code to touch screen
    // set rlayout as global variable ,you can use it in other method
    rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    rlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    });
}
```